# How to move a Sprite along a definite path in Cocos2d using Android(SDK)

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am working on a 2d game. I am using cocos2d with android SDK. I want to move my sprite along a definite path. I am using for that the code below, but I dont get anything in the output.

```
target = CCSprite.sprite("plane1n.png");
CGPoint sprite1pos=CGPoint.ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height);
CCBezierConfig bezier = new CCBezierConfig();bezier.controlPoint_1=CGPoint.ccp(sprite1pos.x,sprite1pos.y);
bezier.controlPoint_2=CGPoint.ccp(winSize.width/4,winSize.height*3/4);
bezier.endPosition=CGPoint.ccp(0,winSize.height/2);
CCBezierTo  action = CCBezierTo.action(3, bezier);
target.runAction(action);
```

Comment: do you get any error..?

Comment: I dont get any error but there is no any effect of the code in my game app.

Comment: try to change that no from 3 to someother. CCBezierTo action = CCBezierTo.action(3,Bezier); try to increase this number and check.